# $(this:selected).val() or .text() returns nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code :

```
<select name="status" statusCode="0" onchange="updateStatus(1)">
    <option value="toSend" statuscode="0">To send</option>
    <option value="send" statuscode="1">Send</option>
    <option value="problem" statuscode="2">Problem</option>
</select>
```

And this jQuery/JS function :

```
function updateStatus(num) {
    alert ($('this:selected').text()); //Return nothing
    alert ($('this:selected').val()); //Return undefined
    alert ($(this).children('option:selected').text()); //Return nothing
}
```

I don't understand why it returns nothing or undefined when I change the select option.

Comment: `$('option:selected', this).text()` try this

Comment: $("this") doesn't return you anything in here. It should only be used in loop

Comment: Just tried, it returns nothing, an empty text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

In Html

```
onchange="updateStatus(1,this)"
```

In JS

```
function updateStatus(num,ev) {

  alert($(ev).val());

}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/ot72zxuw/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#select').change(function() {

  console.log($('option:selected', this).text()); //Return nothing
  console.log($('option:selected', this).val()); //Return undefined
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="status" statusCode="0" id="select">
  <option value="toSend" statuscode="0">To send</option>
  <option value="send" statuscode="1">Send</option>
  <option value="problem" statuscode="2">Problem</option>
</select>
```

Try this way

Comment: If op use change event by jquery  does it's a good coding to select by this `option:selected` ? i think `$(this).val()` will do the job for him.